# swift picture in picture mode

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I am working on video player application and want to add Picture in Picture feature. I added this feature(using AVPictureInPictureController) and it works perfect, except one issue. After I click PiP button, PiP activated but application do not go to the home screen (picture attached). I need to push Home button. 
Ho to hide app and show home screen after PiP button tapped?

Comment: Isn't that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: @LinusG. I want that after pressing pip button: PiP mode enabled, application hidden and home screen shows. Now I need to push home button to show home screen.

Comment: I get your point but I'm saying I believe that this is no issue as you call it, but simply the way Apple designed it to be. I don't know of a way to close the app without terminating it from code so it probably won't work, but as I said: I'm not sure.

Comment: i am unable to make it working... can you share a sample working code?

Answer (score 6):

Starting iOS 14.2, Apple has provided [this API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/3689455-canstartpictureinpictureautomati) to start PIP without user intervention.

You can do it this way without getting your App rejected:

```
if #available(iOS 14.2, *) {                
    pictureInPictureController.canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but if you do this:

```
   func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

        pictureInPictureController.startPictureInPicture() 
    }
```

Then when a user presses the home button or switches apps, the video will go PIP. It's how NetFlix works.

Comment: I would avoid doing that per Apple requirement. "Picture in Picture (PiP) is a user feature that Apple intends to always be under user control. Invoke PiP only in response to a user’s explicit request to do so. If an app invokes PiP in a way that is not under the immediate direction of the user, it will be rejected by the App Store."  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller

Comment: As mentioned by @Soja, it will certainly result in app rejection. Fortunately Apple has provided a way to achieve this. See my answer above.